# Tax exemption on personal loan interest component in India

Tags: india, tax-deduction, personal-loan, tax-exemption

I have taken personal loan for my father business and home construction. The land is on my mom's name. My father is cosigner for the loan. Am I eligible for the tax exemption if yes then under which section.

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Also please mention the documents that I would need to claim the exemption.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I eligible for the tax exemption if yes then under which section.

Generally Personal loans are not eligible for tax exemption. Only housing loans from qualified institutions are eligible for tax deduction.

As per the income tax act; The house should be in your name. The home loans taken from recognised institutions are fully qualified under section 24B and 80C. This means you can claim Interest exemption under 24B and Principal repayment under 80C. The Act also specifies that loan can be taken from friends/relatives for construction of property and will be eligible for Interest exemption under 24B only. The principal will not be eligible for exemption under 80C. Read the [FAQ from Income Tax India](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/tutorials/income-from-house-property-practical.pdf).

There has to be certificate showing how much interest was paid on the said loan. Further there should be records/receipts on how the money was spent.

There is difference of opinion amongst CA. It is best you take a professional advise.

Comment: I read some link 
http://www.charteredclub.com/tax-on-personal-loan/
<br>
https://blog.hrblock.in/tax-planning/section-24-income-tax-benefit-interest-personal-loan/
It says that if the loan purpose is business or  home renovation of something related then interest component of personal loan can be exempted. But my doubt is that land is not on my name and my father is running the business.

Comment: @Sawan Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Income Tax Laws Personal loans are not eligible for tax exemption. Only housing loans from qualified institutions are eligible for tax deduction.

Comment: How does this add anything new to what Dheer already said last year?